# Get top N records using LINQ to Entities

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am using Linq to entities and would like to know if I can get a limited number of records when i query. I just need the top N records as the query do the orderby and other clauses. Is this possible or I will have to get the top N using foreach loop?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874599/get-top-n-records-using-linq-to-entities

Comment: @FaisalShah, the comments points to the same question

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can just use the `.Take` method call to get a couple of result. 
You can read more on this topic [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx).

You need to understand that the query will not be executed unless someone executes the [GetEnumerator()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator.aspx).

Answer (score 42):

There are multiple ways

1)

```
var data = (from p in db.people  
            orderby p.IdentityKey descending 
            select p).Take(100);
```

2)

```
var query = db.Models.Take(100);
```

3) or you can skip certain results

```
var data = (from p in people
            select p).Skip(100);
```

Comment: What if IdentityKey  is Guid? Any solution?

Comment: Then either not sort at all or sort on some other column value

Comment: in this way, it gets all data at first then take 10 of it