# Select top n rows in each group in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to fetch recent contents of each type, currently I'm using something similar to the following code to fetch n records for each type

```
int n = 10;
var contents = Entities.OrderByDescending(i => i.Date);

IQueryable<Content> query = null;
for (int i = 1; i<=5; i++)
{
    if (query == null)
    {
        query = contents.Where(c => c.ContentTypeIndex == i).Take(n);
    }
    else
    {
        query = query.Concat(contents.Where(c => c.ContentTypeIndex == i).Take(n));
    }
}
```

One other solution can be creating an SP, but is it possible to do it by grouping in EF? If not, any cleaner solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get top N records using LINQ to Entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874599/get-top-n-records-using-linq-to-entities)

Comment: @AndyRefuerzo No, not at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
contents.Where(c => c.ContentTypeIndex >= 1 && c.ContentTypeIndex <= 5)
        .GroupBy(c => c.ContentTypeIndex)
        .SelectMany(g => g.Take(n));
```

Note: if you want to select all types of indexes, then you don't need `where` filter here.