# How to get recently searched keywords from a table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-entities

I have a table in SQL Server with following structure:

```
  RecentSearches(
      [Id]         int
     ,[Keyword]    string
     ,[SearchedOn] datetime 
  )
```

I need to query the table to get the 100 most recently searched unique keywords, ordered descendingly by `SearchedOn`.

So for example if I have the following data...

```
          1, adam, 1/1/2014 11:0
          2, sham, 1/1/2014 11:0
          3, ram, 3/1/2014 12:0
          4, sham, 4/1/2014 12:0
          5, ram, 5/1/2014 12:0
          6, sham, 6/1/2014 12:0
          7, ram, 7/1/2014 12:0
          8, john, 8/1/2014 12:0
```

..., the result should show me...

```
        john
        ram 
        sham 
        adam
```

if I query only the 4 top keywords.

I can query using the `distinct` keyword; but then how would I use the `SearchedOn` field because the result should be sorted by the `SearchedOn` field?

Also, I need this query in LINQ to Entities if possible.

Comment: Even through SQL Server 2014 there is no `string` data type.  Readers can infer that you likely mean `nvarchar` or `varchar`, but please clarify.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get top N records using LINQ to Entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874599/get-top-n-records-using-linq-to-entities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
(from rs1 in RecentSearches
 where rs1.SearchedOn ==
     (from rs2 in RecentSearches
      where rs2.Keyword == rs1.Keyword
      select rs2.SearchedOn).Max()
 orderby rs1.SearchedOn descending
 select rs1.Keyword).Take(100)
```

With your sample data, it yields...

```
john
ram
sham
adam
```

...as expected.

A couple key points to note:

1. You do not need `Distinct` per se because the `where` criterion is based on the max `SearchedOn` for each `Keyword` - which is inherently distinct.
2. Since your sample data only contains 4 distinct `Keyword` values, `Take(4)` and `Take(100)` will yield the same result.

Comment: Absolutely.  Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

LINQ

```
var lastHundredSearches = (from p in RecentSearches
                        orderby p.SearchedOn descending
                        select p.Keyword).Take(100);
```

Lambda

```
var lastHundredSearches = RecentSearches.OrderByDescending(p => p.SearchedOn).Select(k=>k.Keyword).Take(100);
```

Comment: The results of this are not distinct.  Given the sample data that the OP provided, this yields `ram` twice.